# gulp to load bootstrap / jquery in .net core

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, .net-core, gulp

trying to move my .net core jquery, bootstrap etc from static files to being updated by package.json / npm. Looks like i need gulp or grunt to do the work. but i cant find any examples from stack or else where that work. Anyone able to give an example or site with one?

Comment: Im trying to follow this: https://blog.bitscry.com/2018/03/13/using-npm-and-gulp-in-visual-studio-2017/  as its the closest ive seen to moving the mvc wwroot to package management. But it loads in the wrong place / isnt loading them properly. If I update the clean and scripts to use wwwroot/lib instead of vendor it errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1 (Recommended)

The best way to make your move/migration as easy & painless as possible, is using [Libman for Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which is brain dead simple to work with.

It just requires you to specify the name of the library you want and the output folder whilst allowing you to cherry-pick files to be copied instead of the entire library.

The good thing with this approach is that it has vs integration and provides intellisense as you type.

## Solution 2

Write a gulp task that will move your required files from npm folder to the wwwroot folder.

Assuming that you already have gulpfile setup, install one additional module called gulp-rename

```
npm i gulp-rename --save-dev
```

**Example**:

```js
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var staticFiles = [
    './node_modules/jQuery/dist/**/*.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*.{js,css}'
];

gulp.task('npmModules', function(){
    // the base option sets the relative root for the set of files,
    // preserving the folder structure
    return gulp.src(staticFiles, { base: './' })
    .pipe(rename(path => path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('node_modules', '')))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/'));
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, 

when i run the above code i get the error:

[19:50:58] Using gulpfile ~\source\repos\npm-test\Gulpfile.js
[19:50:58] Starting 'npmModules'...
[19:50:58] The following tasks did not complete: npmModules
[19:50:58] Did you forget to signal async completion?
Process terminated with code 1.

I also had to add the line below to get it to run:

var gulp = require('gulp');

Comment: Hey, no errors now, but its only pulling in jquery bootstrap is not copied.

Comment: Oh I see. That's because, the css & js files in bootstrap folder are normally another layer deep e.g ../dist/css/, ../dist/js/. Let me readjust accordingly